# SQL To move data when NOT NULL

Tags: mysql, sql, case

This is my first question here, so please be patient with me, so this is a challenge I got while working on a product data. Following is the data I have.

| Column_A | Column_B | Column_C | Column_D | Column_E | Column_F |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A1 | Null | C1 | D1 | Null | F1 |
| Null | Null | C2 | Null | E2 | F2 |
| A3 | B3 | Null | D3 | Null | F3 |
| Null | Null | Null | Null | Null | F4 |

What I'm trying to achieve is to get the data formatted in such a way that it is plausible and convenient for the front-end developers to put it on a website. Basically, i have to move the data into other columns whenever there is a NULL.
For example:

1. If the first, second and fifth columns are Null then the third , fourth and sixth column's data should be    printed in the first three columns respectively
2. If all the first 5 columns are nulls, then the 6th column data should be printed in 1st column and so on

Expected Output :

| Column_A | Column_B | Column_C | Column_D | Column_E | Column_F |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A1 | C1 | D1 | F1 | Null | Null |
| C2 | E2 | F2 | Null | Null | Null |
| A3 | B3 | D3 | F3 | Null | Null |
| F4 | Null | Null | Null | Null | Null |

Is this possible in SQL , if so, please help me with the approach.

Should I do it using case statements or is there a better approach?

Comment: Look at the definition for the COALESCE function before committing to using a CASE.

Comment: Do you have other column that uniquely identify each row, such as id.

Comment: Coalesce returns every first non null right , so would it be I check first n rows and then print it to the first column then check from 2nd column to n rows n print n so on

Comment: Poorly designed database.

Comment: @ahmed yes there is . For instance in the case mentioned in the question there is an ID column as ID 1,2,3,4

Comment: @jarlh that data is raw dump and I’m trying to design a cleaner database that is why I need to get the data together

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may try this:

- unpivot your data and keep the order for each column, i.e. Column_A order 1, Column_B order 2 and so on.
- use `ROW_NUMBER()` function with the unpivoted data where column value is not null to get a new order without nulls.
- pivot the data with conditional aggregation using the defined row number in the previous step to get the desired output.

---

```
with t as
(
  select id, Column_A as col, 1 as ord from table_name
  union all
  select id, Column_b, 2 from table_name
  union all
  select id, Column_c, 3 from table_name
  union all
  select id, Column_d, 4 from table_name
  union all
  select id, Column_e, 5 from table_name
  union all
  select id, Column_f, 6 from table_name
),
t2 as
(
  select *, 
    row_number() over (partition by id order by ord) rn
  from t where col is not null
)

select id,
       max(case when rn =1 then col end) Column_A,
       max(case when rn =2 then col end) Column_B,
       max(case when rn =3 then col end) Column_C,
       max(case when rn =4 then col end) Column_D,
       max(case when rn =5 then col end) Column_E,
       max(case when rn =6 then col end) Column_F
from t2 
group by id
order by id
```

See a [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/AquDBBl7).

Comment: In SQL Server -I'm getting the first three rows right but the row 4 where all are null is getting omitted with the following 

Warning: Null value is eliminated by an aggregate or other SET operation.